# Increase height map resolution to visualize as surface in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, visualization, smoothing

I want to make a visualization of the landscape, obtained during my simulation. The code which I have:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var W = window.innerWidth;
var H = window.innerHeight;
var T = 0;
var heightMap;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
renderer.setSize(W, H);

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, W / H, 0.1, 10000);

var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(80, 80, 10, 10);
var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  'wireframe': true
});
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);

plane.rotation.x = -0.4 * Math.PI;
plane.position.set(0, 0, 0);
scene.add(plane);

camera.position.set(0, 50, 100);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
// add spotlight for the shadows
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
spotLight.position.set(-30, 600, 600);
scene.add(spotLight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
renderer.render(scene, camera);



drawFrame()

function drawFrame() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
  var vLength = plane.geometry.vertices.length;
  heightMap = simulate(T);
  for (var i = 0; i < vLength; i++) {
    plane.geometry.vertices[i].z = heightMap.flat()[i]
  }
  plane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  T += 0.01;
}

function simulate(T) {
  var HM = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
      HM[i][j] = Math.sin(T) * HM[i][j] * 20;
    }
  }

  return HM
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/104/three.min.js"></script>
```

The real function `simulate` is slow, but also produces some height map as output. The problem is, that I could not simulate in a lot of points, as this function is slow. To Have a nice visualization I want just to smooth and increase the resolution of the calculated rough height map.

**Could You give me a piece of advice about how to solve this problem?**

Comment: For continuous vertex position updates, you should look into writing custom shaders. That way you can offload the repetitive calculations to the graphics card, which was built for heavy parallel computations. I recommend you read through https://thebookofshaders.com/ to learn about GLSL shaders, then you can visit [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=custom#webgl_custom_attributes) to see how you can animate vertex positions via a `vertexShader` in Three.js. This way you'll be able to update thousands or millions or vertices at a fraction of the time it would take via CPU.

Comment: Maybe this [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-implement-heatmap/4007?u=prisoner849) will be helpful for you :)

Comment: @Marquizzo, unfortunately, I could not use shaders. The height map which is an output of simulate is a bivariate histogram of simulation results. If I would do it in a shader, then I would oversimulare a lot. What I really need is a bicubic spline or NURBS.